# Changing row height dynamically

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I've two columns on my reactjs aggrid: Ids and Description.Data is being fetched from REST api on Search button click.
If the API returns multiple Ids for a row, I'm displaying them in the cell one below another using line break("
").
E.g.

2101

5102

9808

I need the grid row height to be adjusted automatically, based on the number of Ids being returned.

I've tried various attributes in the header definition as per below. But yet, the row height does not seem to change dynamically.

```
[{
    headerName: "Description",
    resizable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    cellStyle: {
        'white-space': 'normal'
    },
    autoHeight: true
},
{
    headerName: "Ids",
    resizable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    cellStyle: {
        'white-space': 'normal'
    },
    autoHeight: true
}]
```

Any pointers here please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that you get from the api?

Comment: {
"data":[

{
"Description": D1"
"Ids":
[
{
"Id": 2101
}

{
"Id": 5102
}

{
"Id": 9808
}
]

},

{
"Description": D2"
"Ids":
[
{
"Id": 9808
}
]

},

{
"Description": D3"
"Ids":
[
{
"Id": 5102
}

{
"Id": 9808
}
]

]
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

Create customCellRendererComponent

```
function CustomCellRenderer(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.value.map((x, index) => <div key={index}>{x.Id}</div>)}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Then register customCellRenderer in the grid like that

```
function GridExample () {
    const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);
    const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = useState(null);
  
    const onGridReady = (params) => {
      setGridApi(params.api);
      setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
    };
  
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <div
          id="myGrid"
          style={{
            height: '95%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
          className="ag-theme-alpine"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            frameworkComponents={{
              customCellRenderer: CustomCellRenderer,
            }}
            rowData={rowData}
            rowHeight={120}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
          >
            <AgGridColumn
              field="Description"
            />
            <AgGridColumn
              field="Ids"
              cellRenderer="customCellRenderer"
            />
          </AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};
```

See full code example here https://plnkr.co/edit/w7Jar0xaq7yZ4wtJ